# QGIS 2.14 2.5d render appears different in composer and map views

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.14

I'm experimenting with 2.5d rendering for the first time.  It seems to me that the objects are being rendered in a different order between the main working environment and the map composer.

[image: qgis 2.14 work space]
[image: qgis 2.14 map space]

I'm wondering if others are having this issue and if it's a bug, or simply user error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue reported at http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14604

Comment: It's now fixed in the development versions and will be fixed in >=2.14.2 releases.